# Textblock cut the text half, any solution to show the complete text?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The textblock cut off the text into half, any method to solve it?

The problem is shown below.

[image]

Additional information:

Code:

Comment: increase text box height.

Comment: And just as a general advice, dont be shy, share your code! This usally helps a lot in identifying the Problem.

Comment: you're not the first one to ask this, but considering this is your first post. In the future, try to include your own code/attempts to fix it. that way others can see where you went wrong and correct it. But since this is a pretty common problem it's an easy generic fix :)

Comment: Thank you everyone.
Beibeizhu, I tried increasing the textblock height but it still remains the same. Any other solutions?

Andre and Dennis, I will share the code next time.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Jeff,
As beibeizhu mentioned you can increase the TextBlock height. You can (which would be more standard) not set a size which will mean the control will try and demand enough space so it's content fits. To succeed it will have to be inside something which allows it to grow.

See [Layout | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/layout) for additional information on this topic.

If you want to have the TexBlock this small you can alternatively decrease fontsize.

It is standard practice not to set any size on a textblock.

Comment: Rather than auto scaling I think what Andre means is the textbox will demand enough space to fit. So long as it's container lets it, the textbox will then get sufficient space. This is part of how the layout system is designed for flexibility. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/layout

Comment: Yes this is what i mean, thanks for the clarification, also feel free to edit the answer if you want to.

Comment: Just added the link from your comment. Other than that i am now happy with the answer.